# Execute a future returning function on list of elements without failing in scala futures

Tags: scala, asynchronous, exception, future, throw

I am in weird situation of futures , I have this function call `executeCall` which returns a `Future.failed(new Exception("Rts script failed "))` or `Future.successful(this)` now I am calling this function on a list of string like example shown below
Now I have 2-3 scenarios which I want to understand in the sample code below

1. when `executeCall` is called on elements of `elems` then it can either fail or get successful , what I want is that if executing that function returns an failure keep executing the `executeCall` on other elements but in the end execute function should be failed if any of the element fails .
2. When `executeCall` is called on the elments and any of the element returns failure , then code should be sudden exited
3. If i use the `case 1` mentioned as shown below then in that case my code execution get sudden stopped if any of the `elem` fails
4. If i use the `case 2` , code never fails even when some `elem` return failure not able to understand why not
5. Correct me on this question . Firstly we are trying to recover any exception thrown from the the end of `executeCall` but after recovering it  we are converting it into our own exception and then we are storing the response into a variable
6. Correct me on this . In case 2 when we use up a underscore what does it check

```
val elems = Seq("elem1" , "elem2" , "elem3" )
def execute(ctx ): Future[MyContext] = {

    val result = elems.map {
      script => {
        executeCall(script)
          .recoverWith { case e =>
            logger.error(e, s"Failed to execute [${script}] RTS script")
            throw MyOwnException(s"Failed to execute RTS script", e)
          }
      }
    }

// case 1
    Future(ctx) 
// case 2
   Future.sequence(result)
      .map(_ => ctx)
```

Comment: Cannot cancel a `Future`, but you can `traverse` the results. That being said, if you want something to indicate which call failed, the simpler approach is to use an `Either[MyCustomErrorMapping, Result]` type and then resume in the end. It's up to you to decide after that.